# How to Navigate through WEPopoverController in Iphone?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii ,i am using WEPopOverController to popup a page,the page name is account page,when i tap the button in the main page it popups the account page,in account page i have 5 buttons,i write action for each button to navigate to another page.My issue is when i tap the button i didn't navigate to next page,i tried every thing but no luck,is there navigation is not possible in we popover?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:delegate.rootViewController];
self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController] autorelease];
[navigationController release];
```

If this wont work, i would say it's just a bad practice, making navigation hierarchy.

it's much more better to assign to buttons new Popovers. I had an big app where a popover was called from a popover called from a popover called from a popover, because in general there was a rich hierarchy of navigation through settings.
It looked pretty cool and easy in navigation, so i would advice you to do it as well.